# How to stop a backgroundworker while running a function?

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

There is a bunch of processing running in a background thread as a sequence of functions, there is also a form with a cancel button. As usual, the cancelbutton sets the `CancellationPending` bit.

Between each of the function calls, this is checked by:

```
If (worker.CancellationPending) Then
    e.Cancel = True
    Return
End If
```

But if one function (for example for loading a number of files) starts showing error messages, the user wants to stop the program right there, instead of waiting untill the full function has finished. How can I accomplish this?

I could check for the `worker.CancellationPending` bit a number of times within each function, but I feel that might lead to really akward code.

Is there a way to stop a backgroundworker while it's in the middle of running a function?

Comment: As you suggest, check for `worker.CancellationPending` everywhere it might be needed. So in your example, check after every file load attempt.

Comment: Surely there is no reason to keep a BGW running when it failed.  Throw an exception, you'll get it back with e.Error in the RunWorkerCompleted event.  Then show the error.

Comment: @HansPassant The point is that a lot of these errors might be non-fatal, but the user can still decide to abort the process. I will try to restructure it in a better way though.

Comment: Very, very important to keep in mind that this is a *background* worker.  It should not chat with the user.  It can say something when it starts and stops, its ProgressChanged event handler can update (say) a Label.  That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  Just terminating something from the outside at an arbitrary point is generally a bad idea, so the `BackgroundWorker` doesn't support it.  You could look into creating your own `Thread` and then calling `Abort` on that.  That is generally discouraged for the same reason but it is at least possible.

Comment: Ok, clear. I will look into restructuring all my function calls to handle a `worker.CancellationPending` a bit more gracefully. Thanks!